# Python CV2: minAreaRect gives different results on the same image when rotated

Tags: python, opencv, rotation, contour

today I stumbled upon a problem that gave me some headaches and I couldn't figure out a solution.

I want to find the borders of an image with opencv-python / cv2. This is my code:

```
(T, thresh) = cv2.threshold(blurredImage, brightnessMin, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
try: hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
except: hierarchy = []
thresh = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
for contour, hier in zip(contours, hierarchy):
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    rect      = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
    box       = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box       = np.int0(box)
```

So far nothing special.

I want to get the same result for rotated images. The borders should be the same either if the image is rotated 90 degrees or 180 degrees.

But when I rotate my image I get completely different rectangles. Here are two images for comparison:

[image: Normal Orientation]

[image: 180 degree rotation]

The first image is the standard orientation.

And the second one is 180 degrees rotated (and rotated backwards for comparison).

I didn't filtered the rectangles.

I simply don't know why the results are so different. Can somebody maybe help me?

I use opencv-python 4.1.2.30. I know it's a way older version but newer versions made my whole script unusable because some things have changend and I didn't know what exactly was wrong.

My Python Version: Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Did you have a look at your threshold imsge, whether it makes sense? Same for the contours?

Comment: Why are you using cv2.RETR_TREE and not just cv2.EXTERNAL? You only need one rectangle contour to get the bounding box. Be sure you make your image such that the threshold has the object you want white on a black background. Please post your actual input image before you threshold and post whatever processing you are doing before the threshold.